# Android Pay deeplink to saved loyalty card

Tags: android, android-pay, deeplink

I've managed to save a loyalty card to Android Pay inside an Android app by using the google dev guidelines: https://developers.google.com/save-to-android-pay/guides/loyalty/get-started . Right now my implementation just uses the JWT that's retrieved from the back-end to create a link, which can be clicked by the user to save the loyalty card. Now my problem is that i don't have a method of determining whether the loyalty card was saved or not, and if it was saved then how can i deeplink to it? Does anybody have any experience regarding that?

Comment: What did you use as the Save to Android Pay button?

Comment: Just a regular button if I understand your question. I didn't use a button from a specific SDK or with some other configurations, it's just a button with an on click listener that points to a link with the configuration for Android Pay.

Answer (score 0):

Get the object and look for the *"hasUsers"*
https://developers.google.com/save-to-android-pay/reference/v1/loyaltyobject/get
If true object is in a wallet else it is not.
Since an object can exist in multiple wallets it needs to be removed from all the wallets. Have the object and wallet uniquely associated with setting the property *"allowMultipleUsersPerObject"* set to false in the object.
https://developers.google.com/save-to-android-pay/reference/v1/loyaltyobject